# Alternative to Team Foundation Build for continous delivery?

Tags: continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

We currently use TFS 2010 for our source control. Is there an alternative for continuous deployment\builds when we do checkins? We are stuck with TFS 2010, not sure if there are open source alternatives that would work with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We used TFS 2010 for gated checkins and CI builds up until last October and they worked great.  We upgraded to TFS 2015 and now use a mix of older XAML and the new build system builds.

We use Thoughtworks GO! for our CD and pipeline orchestration.  GO! can be triggered by new changesets in TFS.  The two worked great for us.

[image]